# Set custom frame of tab in Android

Tags: android, tabbar

Is it possible to set height and width of tabs in Android? I tried setting customized textview as the indicator of tabspec, setting its height and width to different values, but no matter what its height and width value is, it's always set to the default height and width value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it is quite a bit of a hassle. The layout for the tab widgets uses a fixed height, so you'd have to change that layout directly. One way of doing that is to extend `TabWidget`, override the `addView` method and change the widgets according to your needs.